# MongoDB Reference Issue

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I have two collections set up at the moment. One collection lists all of the products in my store. The other collection stores the ratings on a scale of 1-5. The ratings store in the ratings collection successfully, and the products are stored and listed successfully. However, I am attempting to reference the appropriate rating for the individual product that is listed. I am using an ng-repeat to list all of the products in my product database. I'm not sure what is going on, but my reference to the ratings is returning an empty array.

How can I get the ratings to show for each product?

Product Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    index: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 0,
  },
  rating: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Rating'
  }],
  image: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Product Controller (just the read portion):

```
var Product = require('../models/Product');

module.exports = {

  read: function (req, res) {
    Product.find(req.query)
      .populate('Rating')
      .exec(function (err, result) {
        if (err) { return res.status(500).send(err);}
        console.log("this is in the product ctrl", result);
        {res.send(result);}
      });
  },
};
```

Rating Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ratingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  rating: {
    type: Number,
    enum: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Rating', ratingSchema);
```

Rating Controller (just read and create shown):

```
var Rating = require('../models/Rating');

module.exports = {

  create: function (req, res) {
    var newRating = new Rating(req.body);
    newRating.save(function (err, result) {
      if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
      else res.send(result);
    });
  },

  read: function (req, res) {
    Rating.find(req.query)
    .populate('type')
      .exec(function (err, result) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        else res.send(result);
      });
  }
};
```

Screenshot of view:

[image: The view when adding a rating. Only showing empty array]

If more information is needed please let me know. I thought that something may be wrong with my .populate, but after reading this documentation I think everything is good. I'm stumped.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: The populate call is wrong. This: `.populate('Rating')` should be `.populate('rating')`. This is because it is the "path" in the document that is to be populated and **not** the "Model name" which is what you seem to be doing here. You should also probably consider calling the field "ratings", as it is an array an a plural is logical for a list.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. After changing the name to 'rating' the same issue still occurs. The name change seems to have no effect.

Comment: Check your references to see that they actually match something expected. The basic here is "rating" is the field name so that is the path to be populated as opposed to the name you were asking for. Also run without populate to see the reference values that are stored, as if populate does not match then it will empty the array.